# Get method is not working in Restsharp using C#

Tags: c#, json, rest, restsharp

Get Method is not working... below code display all names or other attributes in richtext box from json using restsharp...there is no error but Ouput is not came help me to solve this...

```
var client = new RestClient("http://www.jsongenerator.com/api/json/get/cfBwXjwjci?indent=2");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
var queryResult = client.Execute<List<Detail>>(request).Data;
foreach (var rl in queryResult)
     {
        richTextBox1.Text = rl.name;
     }

public class Detail
    {
        public string city { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Blood { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is json

```
{
  "Details": [
    {
      "city": "Londan", 
      "id": 1, 
      "Blood": "O+", 
      "name": "Nicolas"
    }, 
    {
      "city": "USA", 
      "id": 2, 
      "Blood": "A+", 
      "name": "Jhon"
    }, 
    {
      "city": "India", 
      "id": 3, 
      "Blood": "B-", 
      "name": "Shiva"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Whats the statuscode

Comment: Doesn't show anything

Comment: What do you mean doesnt show anything, of course it does

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems:

1) "http://www.jsongenerator.com/api/json/get/cfBwXjwjci?indent=2" - doesn't work

2) If you provided a correct JSON example then you should use "RootObject" here:

```
client.Execute<List<Detail>>(request).Data;
```